# Merging rows when counting - Django/SQL

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    unique_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I would like to get:

- the count of the different **category_codes** used
- count of the different **unique_codes** used
- count of the different **combination of category_code and unique_code** used

---

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django/SQL solution as requested:

the count of the different **category_codes** used:

```
category_codes_cnt = Item.objects.values('category_codes').distinct().count()
```

count of the different **unique_codes** used:

```
unique_codes_cnt = Item.objects.values('unique_codes').distinct().count()
```

count of the different **combination of category_code and unique_code** used:

```
codes_cnt = Item.objects.values('category_codes', 'unique_codes').distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste too much time trying finesse a cool SQL solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_cat_code = defaultdict(int)
count_unique_code = defaultdict(int)
count_combo_code = defaultdict(int)
for obj in Item.objects.all():
    count_cat_code[obj.category_code] += 1
    count_unique_code[obj.unique_code] += 1
    count_combo_code[obj.category_code,obj.unique_code] += 1
```

That will do it.  And it will work reasonably quickly.  Indeed, if you do some benchmarking, you may find that -- sometimes -- it's as fast as a "pure SQL" statement.

[Why?  Because RDBMS must use a fairly inefficient algorithm for doing GROUP BY and Counts.  In Python we have the luxury of assuming some things based on our application and
our knowledge of the data.  In this case, for example, I assumed that it would all fit
in memory.  An assumption that cannot be made by the RDBMS internal algorithms.]

Comment: @S.Lott: Thanks!! :) But what if it contains 1Million rows, which is kind of the case here. Any tips?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  SQL isn't much faster than Python for this.  All million rows must be read no matter what.  SQL often has to sort them into temporary storage before it can do the GROUP BY, leading to a **O** ( n log(n) ) kind of performance.  In Python you make one fast pass through the data collecting everything you need.  Your hash tables are all **O** (1) so it's net **O** (n).

Comment: otoh, that does mean every row has to be marshalled/transmitted/unmarshalled, which may turn out to be more overhead than hashing. don't guess, measure. at least for a small example I used, postgresql will do a hash aggregate anyway.

Comment: @araqnid: "does mean every row has to be marshalled/transmitted/unmarshalled".  Yes.  "which may turn out to be more overhead than hashing."?  What?  The database can't do the hashing for you.  And GROUP BY in SQL may not involve any hashing.  GROUP BY in SQL often involves an huge, expensive sort.  A table scan can be faster.

Comment: This will be significantly slower than a SQL query that calculates a total within the database program and transmits result to the client, especially if the object is large and plentiful.

Comment: postgresql can and does use hash tables to perform aggregation rather than sorting when it can. a "table scan" will be involved regardless of whether the db or client does aggregation, why do you mention it? Transmitting all the data to the client can be a considerable overhead, the client would have to be considerably more efficient at aggregating it for it to be worthwhile. Which brings us back to: measure, don't guess.

Comment: @araqnid: "postgresql can and does use hash tables"  Good to know. "measure, don't guess" I did.  That's why I posted it.

Comment: @vls: "This will be significantly slower than a SQL query".  Sometimes.  However, sometimes not.  It varies with database, network connection, volume of data, etc.  Python's dictionary processing is so fast that it can be "considerably more efficient at aggregating".

Comment: good-- but the person who needs to measure is the OP with the real data set!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct unique_code) as unique_code_count,
       count(distinct category_code) as category_code_count,
       count(*) as combination_count
from (select unique_code, category_code, count(*) as combination_count
      from item
      group by unique_code, category_code) combination
```